# g++ compiling errors in ubuntu

Tags: c++, gcc, ubuntu, permissions, g++

Everytime I try to compile in ubuntu using g++ I get the following errors

```
g++ test.cpp -o test
/usr/bin/ld: 1: /usr/bin/ld: /bin: Permission denied
/usr/bin/ld: 2: /usr/bin/ld: test.cpp: not found
/usr/bin/ld: 3: /usr/bin/ld: test.cpp: not found
/usr/bin/ld: 4: /usr/bin/ld: test.cpp: not found
/usr/bin/ld: 5: /usr/bin/ld: test.cpp: not found
/usr/bin/ld: 6: /usr/bin/ld: test.cpp: not found
/usr/bin/ld: 7: /usr/bin/ld: test.cpp: not found
/usr/bin/ld: 8: /usr/bin/ld: test.cpp: not found
/usr/bin/ld: 9: /usr/bin/ld: test.cpp: not found
/usr/bin/ld: 10: /usr/bin/ld: test.cpp: not found
/usr/bin/ld: 11: /usr/bin/ld: test.cpp: not found
/usr/bin/ld: 12: /usr/bin/ld: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

I have removed and re-installed g++ numerous times. The chmod for /usr/bin and /usr/bin/ld is 755 and the weird thing is I can run it `g++ -c test.cpp` however then I can't run the .o file. I am not entirely sure what is the issue.

Answer (score 5):

First, a .o file is not meant to be run, it's meant to be linked together with other object files (.o) and libraries (in particular the C++ and C standard libraries). However, I would guess from your error messages that this would probably not work.

From your error message it sounds like perhaps you are running this command in the `/bin` directory. This is improper. You should be running it in some directory you have write access to (like your home directory). Furthermore it's telling you that it can't find your test.cpp file, are you sure you have `cd`'ed into the proper directory?

Answer (score 0):

First of all,`g++ -c test.cpp` only compile or assemble the source code, but do not link. The ultimate output is an object file. which is .o file in you case. You can't run the .o file.

As mentioned above `g++ -c test.cpp` just ignore the linking part so `ld` won't be used, that's why the `g++ -c test.cpp` works for you.

You can switch to root user and run `g++ test.cpp -o test` again. If it works, you may have a permission problem on `/usr/bin` or `/usr/bin/ld`

Comment: Tried running it as sudo no luck and even set the chmod for all the directories to 777.

Comment: You don't have to chmod for the directories, but for the executable files. I'm still confused about your case, let me think for a while.

Comment: Okay, last try, I'm not sure may be you need install build-essential package.Try sudo apt-get install build-essential